# Include .org.gpg files in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, gpg

How do I include `.org.gpg` files in my `org-agenda-files`? By default, it ignores them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `org-agenda-file-regexp` as shown to include `.org.gpg` files, then set `org-agenda-files` as usual.

```
(unless (string-match-p "\\.gpg" org-agenda-file-regexp)
  (setq org-agenda-file-regexp
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\\\.org" "\\\\.org\\\\(\\\\.gpg\\\\)?"
                                  org-agenda-file-regexp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research and experimentation, I settled on this which works:

```
(setq org-agenda-file-regexp "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\\(\\.gpg\\\)?\\'")
```

When building an agenda, org-mode will (by default) look for files ending on .org. This is represented as a regular expression `\\`[^.].*\.org\'`, which means to look for any file that does not start with a dot (.), followed by any characters, and ending with .org.

Adding `\\\(\\.gpg\\\)?` says that it can optionally end with ".gpg" as well.

Thus, setting org-agenda-file-regexp to the value above will include all files ending in .org or .org.gpg.

Comment: You might want to describe how it answers the question - how it works / what it does. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion! I will add some more explanation as to why this works :-)